# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with viewWillTransitionToSize and Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

This code used to work in our today extension, but now EXC_BAD_ACCESS with using Xcode 6.3.  What is the new problem?

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: I read on the Apple forums that it is a bug.  Workaround:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone mentioned to me they think this is an Apple bug.  Here's a workaround (or the solution):

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    if let safeCoordinator = coordinator as UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?
    {
        println("coordinator != nil")
        safeCoordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in
            self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
            }, completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {
        println("coordinator == nil")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get `"coordinator == nil"` every time in my Today Widget which prevents the crash but also prevents access to `size` which is my goal. Are you getting `safeCoordinator ` set to a non nil value each time?

Comment: Sometimes it was nil.  I dont understand it