# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with viewWillTransitionToSize and Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, swift2, xcode7

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS with viewWillTransitionToSize in Xcode 7. the solution posted here [EXC_BAD_ACCESS with viewWillTransitionToSize and Xcode 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805843/exc-bad-access-with-viewwilltransitiontosize-and-xcode-6-3/30087332#30087332) worked up untill I upgraded to XCode 7.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator:   UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    if let safeCoordinator = coordinator as UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?
    {
        // Error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
        print("coordinator != nil")
        safeCoordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in
            self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        print("coordinator == nil")
    }
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Any news on this? Did you get it solved?

Comment: **Nope**, unfortunately not.